# Including today's date in export of tibble to Excel in R

Tags: r, excel

Hi I am looking to append the current date when exporting a tibble to an Excel file - haven't included all code but can someone please advise how to do this within R? Below code define's today's date and saves the file I have as a workbook but how to have file name appended with today's date? Thank you.

```
CurrentDate <- Sys.Date()
saveWorkbook(wb, "Tester.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `paste0`.

Today, 2021-10-14, this will save the file with the name `Tester2021-10-14.xlsx`.

```
CurrentDate <- Sys.Date()

filename <- paste0("Tester", CurrentDate, ".xlsx")

saveWorkbook(wb, filename, overwrite = TRUE)
```